# Jackson serializing issue with Inheritance and method overloading

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jersey

I'm using Jackson along with Jersey + Jetty for my RESTful application. The jackson libraries are: `jackson-annoations-2.8.0` `jackson-core-2.8.9` and `jackson-databind-2.8.9`.

I'm unable to make Jackson output the values of the subclass. It always outputs the values of the inheriting class. Although I do explicitly supply the concrete object. The scenario is a bit difficult to word it properly, I hope the following example explains it better.

Here is the pseudo-code of the classes that get serialized:

- Parent0.java:

  ```
  class Parent0 {
    protected Child0 child;

    public Parent0() {}

    public Child0 getChild() {
       return child;
    }

    public void setChild(Child0 child) {
       this.child = child;
    }
  }
  ```
- Parent1.java:

  ```
  class Parent1 extends Parent0 {}
  ```
- Child0.java:

  ```
  class Child0 {
    protected int id;

    public Child0() {}

    public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
       return this.id;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Child0 child0 = (Child0) o;
        return id == child0.id;
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
     }
  }
  ```
- Child1.java:

  ```
  class Child1 extends Child0 {
     private String childName;

     public Child1() {}

     public String getChildName() {
        return childName;
      }

      public void setChildName(String childName) {
         this.childName = childName;
      }    
  }
  ```
- Inside the main controller:

  ```
  Parent0 p0 = new Parent0();
  Child0 c0 = new Child0();
  c0.setId(0);
  p0.setChild(c0);

  Parent0 p1 = new Parent1();
  Child1 c1 = new Child1();
  c1.setId(1);
  c1.setChildName("C1");
  p1.setChild(c1);

  serializeAndPrint(p0); // #1
  serializeAndPrint(p1); // #2
  ```

Output:

```
    #1 Parent0.json
    {
        child: {
            id: 0
        }
    }

    #2 Parent1.json
    {
        child: {
            id: 1
        }
    }
```

Expected:

```
    #2 Parent1.json
    {
        child: {
            id: 1,
            childName: "C1"
        }
    }
```

The serialization is handled by the Jersey framework. I annotate my endpoint with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` which basically takes care of the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

What is the implementation of your serializeAndPrint method?
I wrote a unit test to reproduce the issue:

```
public class JsonTest {

@Test
public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Parent0 p0 = new Parent0();
    Child0 c0 = new Child0();
    c0.setId(0);
    p0.setChild(c0);

    Parent0 p1 = new Parent1();
    Child1 c1 = new Child1();
    c1.setId(1);
    c1.setChildName("C1");
    p1.setChild(c1);

    System.out.println(mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter()).writeValueAsString(p0));
    System.out.println(mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter()).writeValueAsString(p1));

}
```

}

The output is exactly what you expected:

```
{
  "child" : {
  "id" : 0
  }
}
{
  "child" : {
   "id" : 1,
   "childName" : "C1"
   } 
}
```

Comment: The serialization is handled by the Jersey framework. I annotate my endpoint with `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` which basically takes care of the conversion. Since your test case passed, I think it's got something to do with Jersey convertors rather than Jackson itself.
I'll edit my question to provide this information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Jackson is the JSON provider being used (as [Clive Bixby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8668332/clive-bixby) shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002439/2587435)). Those dependencies (libraries) that you say you have are not enough. They are only the core dependencies for Jackson. Jackson *does* have a library that support JAX-RS and if you are using Jersey, there is a Jersey wrapper for the Jackson JAX-RS support library.

If you are using Jersey 2.x, then the dependency you need is `jersey-media-json-jackson`. After you add the dependency, you should register the `JacksonFeature` with your Jersey app configuration (either web.xml or your ResourceConfig). Currently there is probably some other JSON provider that you are using and you don't know it. Check for any other `jersey-media-json-xxx` dependency. If you have any other than Jackson, then remove it. If `jersey-media-json-jackson` is the only provider you have in the classpath, then you will not need to register the `JacksonFeature`, it will default to being the one used.

If you are using Jersey 1.x, then the dependency is `jersey-json`.  After you add the dependency, then you need to set the `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` property to true in your app configuration (either an init-param with web.xml or in your ResourceConfig)

**Note:** If you are manually adding jars and not using a dependency manager like Maven, then it will be a little more leg work in figuring out all the exact jars you need, as `jersey-media-json-jackson` *or* `jersey-json` both depend on a few other jars.